# What is the grammatical name of the first part of the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatical name of the first part of the following sentence in bold?

**One of the greatest playwrights of the English Renaissance**, Christopher Marlowe is known for his plays *Doctor Faustus* and *Tamburlaine*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition). The bolded text is an appositive.

It helps to think about what the first part of the sentence is doing functionally. It is a noun phrase that describes Christopher Marlowe. (Who is Marlowe? One of the greatest playwrights of the English Renaissance!) More than that, as a noun phrase next to another noun phrase, it could substitute for the noun phrase it joins:

> One of the greatest playwrights of the English Renaissance is known for his plays *Doctor Faustus* and *Tamburlaine*.

That is a bit riddle-like but functions as a sentence.

So this noun phrase, close in position to the noun phrase it helps gloss, is an appositive. Examples like [the one here](http://www.german-latin-english.com/basicdiagrams26-30.htm) tend to highlight some trait or quality of the main noun phrase:

> My grandfather, **a lifelong non-smoker**, attributed his longevity to a healthy lifestyle.

One could also rearrange the sentence to look like yours:

> **A lifelong non-smoker**, my grandfather attributed his longevity to a healthy lifestyle.

Apposition can happen with the subject or predicate of a sentence.

> The plays *Doctor Faustus* and *Tamburlaine* were written by Christopher Marlowe, **one of the greatest playwrights of the English Renaissance.**